# NotBlank assert and "must be of the type string, null given"

Tags: forms, symfony, assert

With Symfony 3.3, I have an entity With NotBlank assert :

```
class UserContributorVersion
{
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * Set name
     * 
     * @param string $name
     */
    public function setName(string $name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
    }
}
```

But If I validate form with novalidate attribute, I have this error :

> Argument 1 passed to AppBundle\Entity\UserContributorVersion::setName() must be of the type string, null given

I don't understand, why force setName(string $name = null) if I have NotBlank assert ?

Thanks you :)

Comment: because if you just pressed the submit button without inserting any data, then the fields are NULL, and you typehinted that you expect a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Validation is performed on form data. If form is supposed for some entity (option `data_class` is set) then form data is entity that should be modified. Validation is performed after request values are set to form data (in your case entity) fields.

You can find form submit flow here: 
https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/events.html#submitting-a-form-formevents-pre-submit-formevents-submit-and-formevents-post-submit

[image]

Validation is registered as `FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT` event. Request values are set to form data just before `POST_SUBMIT` event.

Comment: Thanks you very much :) What is the best solution ? Add assert in formType (and remove in entity) or add "= null" on setName() in entity ? :) Thanks

Comment: I think that 2-nd